# How to delete empty cells and shift up in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to delete empty cells in a given range and shift the column up to the desired display as shown below? Closest I came was

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:C1; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A2:C,,999^99)), " "))})
```

which removes empty cells, but splits the first names and surnames into separate cells, which I have not figured out how to avoid. Pfa a made-up sample of current and desired displays:

[Current Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA9CS.png)

[Desired Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkT9O.png)

Answer (score 4):

I'm new at this, but I came up with a bit of a brute force method, which may help you.

```
={
 {(A1:C1)};
 {FILTER(A2:A100,A2:A100<>"");indirect("N1:N" & 100-counta(A2:A100))},
 {FILTER(B2:B100,B2:B100<>"");indirect("N1:N" & 100-counta(B2:B100))},
 {FILTER(C2:C100,C2:C100<>"");indirect("N1:N" & 100-counta(C2:C100))}}
```

Assuming your data block is in columns A1:C100, this formula filters blank cells from each individual column, and then pads each column with blank cells at the bottom, to make the three arrays equal in length/dimension.

Note that in "100-counta(...", the 100 is the expected maximum length of your data column.
This could be calculated, and must be the same for all three columns.

Note also that the first array is horizontal (ends with a semi-colon), followed by the three columns, stacked beside each other (ends with a comma).

Here is a working example.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MGaqqGrkmIliuAzEqxPtdEVZXWPN2K5W7jFFM-ZnwgE/edit?usp=sharing

If I missed something you were trying to achieve, let me know.

Also, I'm sure that there is a more elegant way to do this, or one not requiring the use of a block of "reserved" blank cells, but I couldn't think of that at the moment.

Edit:  The formula as follows also works.  But you need to remember to set the "100" value to be equal to the number of rows in your data block, since we pad the columns with the necessary number of blanks rows, after removing the blank cells in each column.

```
={
 {(A1:C1)};
 {FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"");indirect("N1:N" & 100-counta(A2:A))},
 {FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"");indirect("N1:N" & 100-counta(B2:B))},
 {FILTER(C2:C,C2:C<>"");indirect("N1:N" & 100-counta(C2:C))}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback.  My first answer - feels great to believe I can return some help, after all of the great tips and tricks I've learned on SO.

Comment: Save the feeling and keep it up :)